# Snow fall effect not appearing on top of my blog contents

Tags: javascript, animation

I had copied a snow fall JavaScript code in body of my blogger website's code.

But snow only falls under blog posts ( Not on top of content )

How can I correct this ?

```js
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
(function($){$.fn.snow=function(options){var  $flake=$('<div id="flake"  />').css({'position':'absolute','top':'-50px'}).html('&#10052;'),documentHeight=$(document).height(),documentWidth=$(document).width(),defaults={minSize:10,maxSize:20,newOn:500,flakeColor:"#FFFFFF"},options=$.extend({},defaults,options);var  interval=setInterval(function(){var  startPositionLeft=Math.random()*documentWidth-100,startOpacity=0.5+Math.random(),sizeFlake=options.minSize+Math.random()*options.maxSize,endPositionTop=documentHeight-40,endPositionLeft=startPositionLeft-100+Math.random()*200,durationFall=documentHeight*10+Math.random()*5000;$flake.clone().appendTo('body').css({left:startPositionLeft,opacity:startOpacity,'font-size':sizeFlake,color:options.flakeColor}).animate({top:endPositionTop,left:endPositionLeft,opacity:0.2},durationFall,'linear',function(){$(this).remove()});},options.newOn);};})(jQuery);//]]></script><script>$(document).ready(  function(){
$.fn.snow({ minSize: 10, maxSize: 50, newOn: 400, flakeColor: &#39;#ffffff&#39; });
});</script>
```

Screenshot : [image: Snow Fall on Blog]

Answer (score 0):

I just got it done. I saw there is **div** with id called **flake** in JS code.

Just added following to the style :

```
#flake {
  z-index: 9999;
        }
```